# How to create dynamic select option?

Tags: php, html

I am making Hotel Reservation System, So in select city option it will fetch the data from data base, show the only cities which are in the database. I Just hard coded in the following code, It will always show all city. How to make dynamic select?
style,

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="width: 80px" >
                <p style="float: left;"><label for="select-choice-1" class="select" >Select City</label> 
                                    <select
                                            name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
                                            <option value="chennai">Chennai</option>
                                            <option value="bangalore">Bangalore</option>
                                            <option value="delhi">Delhi</option>
                                            <option value="kolkata">Kolkata</option>
                                            <option value="hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
                                            <option value="secunderabad">Secunderabad</option>
                                            <option value="mumbai">Mumbai</option>
                                    </select>
                                </p>                                
            </div>
```

Comment: Do a database query, and write a loop that creates an `<option>` element for each row in the table. There must be hundreds of examples here and on tutorial sites.

Comment: Hi @Barmar sir, thanks for your reply please describe it

Comment: You should show what you tried, we're not here to do your work for you. We're here to help you fix the code when you can't get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
<select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
<?php $mysql = mysql_query("select city from citytable");
 while($fetchcity = mysql_fetch_array($mysql)){ ?>
  <option value="mumbai"><?php echo $fetchcity['cityfieldname'];  ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi @Glizzweb, sorry but I am new web technology, Please tell how to call this code, in select option if php code is in separate file php file?

Comment: first u must connect ur database then u can run this code

Comment: No I have to store this php code into separate file and call that file form the this      <select> call getcity.php </select> like that how I will do that?

Comment: want to ajax function

Comment: K, please tell me How I will do that? thanks

Comment: sure ill wait a moment

Comment: check this link u can get idea about this - http://www.infotuts.com/cascaded-dropdown-jquery-ajax-php/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67692/discussion-between-neelabhsingh-and-glizzweb).

Comment: Thanks for  sharing this links It was the same i was looking,